# How to add screenshot feature in accessibility service in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, screen-capture, accessibilityservice

### Issue Description

I'm developing an Android accessibility service in Kotlin for periodic screen capture. However, I'm facing issues with the `rootNode` being null, impacting the reliability of screen capture.

### Code Snippet

```kotlin
class ScreenshotService : AccessibilityService() {

    private lateinit var rootNode: AccessibilityNodeInfo

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        rootNode = rootInActiveWindow
        // Other logic for handling accessibility events...
        captureScreen()
    }

    private fun captureScreen() {
        try {
            // Attempt to capture the screen using rootNode
            // ...
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        // Handle interruptions (if needed)
    }
}


i tried the above code but i m getiing null any kind of help would be useful.
```